# Map array of strings to another array of strings using configurable logic

Tags: c#, arrays, mapping

If I have an array of strings, and I want to create a "generic" transformer that takes the array as input, along with a "mapping configuration", and produces another array of strings according to the mapping configuration, how would I go about doing so?

E.g.,

> input: ["hello", "world", "to", "all", "junk"] 
> mapper config:
>
> - Concatenate hello + world (i.e. combine position 0 and 1)
> - Concatenate to + all (i.e. combine position 2 and 3)
> - Drop junk (i.e. delete position 4)
>
> Output: ["hello world", "to all"]

Comment: Should the "mapping configuration" be data-driven or be a piece of code? Which mapping operations have to be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a method like this:

`string[] Transform(string[] inputs, Transformation[] transformations)`

Each Transformation could have a source, an operation, and a destination. For your examples, the transformations data might look like this:

```
[
 {
  Source: 0,
  Operation: “SetDestination”,
  Destination: 0
 },
 {
  Source: 1,
  Operation: “ConcatenateDestinationSpaceSource”,
  Destination: 0
 },
 {
  Source: 2,
  Operation: “SetDestination”,
  Destination: 1
 },
 {
  Source: 3,
  Operation: “ConcatenateDestinationSpaceSource”,
  Destination: 1
 }
]
```

The psuedocode for the method would look something like this:

```
foreach(transformation in transformations)
{
    switch(transformation.Operation)
    {
        case SetDestination:
            output[transformation.Destination] = input[transformation.Source];
            break;
        case ConcatenateDestinationSpaceSource:
            output[transformation.Destination] = output[transformation.Destination] + “ “ + input[transformation.Source];
            break;
    }
}
```

No operation would be needed for the "junk" as it would simply never be placed in the output.

Depending on any other operations and and your chosen data structure, the output may need to be resized as you go. This also assumes the mapping configuration is expected to be applied in a given order.